# Can we deactive the Lookup filter in the managed package

Tags: managed-package

Can we deactive the Lookup filter  on managed-released Custom Fields

Comment: Have you tried anything to verify it?

Comment: I Tried and i can deactivate it but when i try to install this upgrade version in another org I am getting an error

Comment: Are you the developer or end-user?

Comment: What error are you getting. That may be helpful information or we could keep guessing

Answer (score 1):

This is 100% possible as of writing this response. I own a managed package and ran into this scenario.

We had a field which had a required lookup filter in one package version. Deactivated it in the next package version and it installed/upgraded without issue.

You are unable to fully remove the Lookup Filter from the field if it is in a managed.

One thing to watch out for is if you are at the maximum amount of lookup filters and you want to replace one I would build a pre-release to remove one first before adding. Other components in SF managed packages act similar so might want to be safe.

Super old question but it could use an answer.